# What does "Feudovassalism" mean?

Tags: meaning

I searched around but can't seem to find a definition for this word. Does anybody know what it means?

Comment: Look up *feudal* and *vassal*....

Answer (score 2):

It is a mixture of two words, ***feudal*** and ***vassal*** (as a noun). *Feudal* pertained to Europe's legal and military customs existing from the 9th to the 15th century, and *vassal* meant a subservient state or country.

So when combined, it referred to a state that was under the control of another country inside of a medieval system.